# Strict Standards: Declaration of item issue

Tags: php, standards, public-html

I have been migrating an old site over from ispmanager to cpanel.  I have gotten most things up but am running into this error line at the top of the page.

Strict Standards: Declaration of item::put() should be compatible with table::put($page = 0) in /home/joseycues/public_html/item.php on line 0

Does anyone know what this means and have a fix for it?

Comment: You have a class and subclass, and they have different parameter lists in their `put()` methods.

Comment: @Barmar how would I fix that and where do I look?  I am not a developer so I am trying to troubleshoot this and get it resolved.  Thanks!

Comment: `item::put()` needs to have a `$page` parameter, even if it ignores it.

Comment: You can also just ignore the warning, it doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: @Barmar where do I put it?  This is what I see for put on item.php.   # # # #
# override put() method, set modified_date to current date
function put()
 {
 $this->putvalue("entered_date", date("YmdHis"));
 $this->putvalue("modified_date", date("YmdHis"));
 
 return parent::put();
 }

Comment: `function put($page = 0) ...`

Comment: @Barmar thanks.  That got rid of the error.  I appreciate it.